# Can any body tell me how to transform a transformer?

Tags: transforms

Im new to blender , very new indeed.i have blender 2.78. Yesterday i downloaded a transformer model (optimus) both robot and vehicle. I tried a lot but could not find a way how to transform it from robot to vehicle or vice versa.can anybody please help me out. I downloaded the model in .obj format from the website www.tf3dm.com.

If anyone wants to provide me with a link to tutorial website please make sure that the tutorial is in text form as i have poor network connection due to which i cannot watch huge videos. Please help me.

Comment: welcome to the site. Unfortunately,  IMO, your question is out of scope of the site. I'd suggest posting instead to forums like those at Blender artist.

Comment: agree with above, but anyone that would like to help you needs to know more about what model you have downloaded, maybe from where exactly, its format, etc.

Comment: I provided info

Comment: You may want to look at [this model](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/61772) for some inspiration - it was used in a [cgcookie tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLyhbqBJB_o) as well as a [school project](https://cgcookie.com/2015/07/27/the-transformer-has-landed/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to rig your model (plenty tutorials online on rigging characters)
Or
Separate the objects you want to move from the original mesh (edit mode, select faces, edges or vertices that you want, press P, separate by selection) and then you can control that object independtly (arms, legs or other) as they are now different objects.
to perform an animation, you must watch tutorials on keyframe an object, but basically, you move an object (rotation and translation) to where you want, select the frame on the timeline, and press I to keyframe that position on that time. If you repeat this process for several times, Blender will interpolate the motion you keyframed. For better control, you might also find usefull to know how to follow curves for motion, or how to set motion constraints.
Rigging, weight edition and keyframe of the rigs would be the best for you.
here is a random introdutory video on this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

Comment: Thanks for that. I learned to rig yesterday. Is that a way we can transform a transformer or is there any easier way? Can you provide me with a text tutorial website for that plz.

Comment: you can try the following playlist of tutorials (he has made several videos regarding transformers):
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL24F12F585628CCAA

Comment: or this other playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLeeE9RhUxh80jnZxxF6j8Ihlyq5AFiHYf